# How to check if a larger array contains a certain smaller array?

Tags: javascript

For homework I need to write a program which accepts two parameters, which are natural numbers arrays, completed with the guard (0).

The program should check if the sequence of elements (without the 0) contained in the second array fully appears anywhere in the first array. If so, then the program returns the index of the element with which the first array starts the sequence of elements contained in the second array. If there is no such sequence, then the program returns `-1`. If there are several such sequences, it should return the index of the first of the found sequences (the one with the smallest index).

Examples:

```
-> find([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 0], [6, 8, 0])

-> 2

-> find([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 0], [10, 12, 14, 0])

-> -1
```

Now I have written the code that partially works but doesn't seem to pass all the tests.

```
function find(tab1, tab2){
    var index = [];
    var num=0;
    for(var i=0;tab2[i]!=0;i++){
        for(var j=0;tab1[j]!=0;j++){
            if(tab2[i]==tab1[j]){
                index[num] = j;
                num++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(index.length == tab2.length-1){
    return index[0];
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Basically I don't know if the break is the correct thing to add here as I am not sure how it works in JavaScript(which loops it breaks).

Comment: The break will exit the inner for loop. Execution will then continue with the next iteration of the outer for loop.

Comment: I for one believe impérative code looks ugly. Food for thoughts: can you do this using an array reducer or filter? Check for them on MDN (google is your friend). I would try breaking down the problem and writing smaller pure functions. This will make your code declarative. You should apply the principle “Tell, don’t ask” (google this).

Comment: There’s also array.includes and array.indexOf. Read the api on Array on MDN. It will help you. And read some stuff about functional programming (learnyouahaskell website or the course on pluralsight)

Comment: As this is a homework assignment, using array.includes and array.IndexOf doesn't really helps him to learn whatever the teacher is trying to teach him.  While I love functional programming and Haskell, this is a bad advice at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested loop with a temporary index.

```js
function find(source, needle) {
  for (var i = 0; source[i] != 0; i++) {
    var k = i;
    var j = 0;
    while (source[k] != 0 && needle[j] != 0) {
      if (source[k++] != needle[j++]) {
        break; // mismatch between source and needle 
      }
    }
    if (needle[j] == 0) {
      return i; // full match with entire needle
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

var res = find([ 1, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0], [2, 3, 4, 0]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend reworking your approach a bit... currently you're checking your subset against your entire set which is the opposite of what you want. You want to loop through your entire set, check your given set value against your first subset value, and then loop through to check the rest of the values for a match. This is the approach I would recommend:

```js
var fullSet = [1, 6, 37, 54, 3, 87, 37, 15, 9, 21, 53];
var subSet1 = [37, 15, 9];
var subSet2 = [37, 54, 3];
var subSet3 = [3, 90, 512];

function find(full, sub) {
  //Loop entire fullset
  for(var i = 0; i < full.length; i++) {
    //Current fullset value and first subset value match
    if(full[i] == sub[0]) {
      var matches = true; //Toggle for if entire subset does not match
      //Loop through subset
      for(var j = 0; j < sub.length; j++) {
        //Check current full set value against subset value
       if(full[i + j] != sub[j]) {
          matches = false;
          break;
        } 
      }
      //It managed to last the entire subset without finding a mismatch
      //We can thus safely return the current fullset index
      if(matches) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  //Return -1 if no matches found
  return -1;
}

console.log(find(fullSet, subSet1));
console.log(find(fullSet, subSet2));
console.log(find(fullSet, subSet3));
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` in JavaScript

> terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers program control to the statement following the terminated statement.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Now, what you want to do is, foreach position in the first array, review if the second array starts in this position (and it is fully contained). If yes, voila! You can return this index as the result because this is the smallest index that contains the array (if it was not the smallest you would had find it before).

```js
function find(tab1, tab2) {
  for(var i = 0; tab1[i] != 0; i++) {
    if( canIFindSecondArrayStartingAtPosition(tab1, tab2, i) ) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  // if you haven't returned yet it means that tab2 was not found!
  return -1;
}
```

Now, how do you implement the function `canIFindSecondArrayStartingAtPosition`?

You want to visit each position on the second array, and review if the number in this position is the number in the first array in the same position + the initial index. If no, then the second array cannot be found and you can immediately return false.

At the end, if you were able to iterate over all the second array (and find all the numbers) then you return true.

Try to implement it without looking at my code:

> So the whole solution would look like.
>
> ```js
> function canIFindSecondArrayStartingAtPosition(tab1, tab2, initialPosition) {
>     for(var i=0; tab2[i]!=0; i++) {
>       if( tab2[i] != tab1[i + initialPosition] ) {
>         return false;
>       }
>     }
>
>     return true;
> }
>
> function find(tab1, tab2) {
>   for(var i = 0; tab1[i] != 0; i++) {
>     if( canIFindSecondArrayStartingAtPosition(tab1, tab2, i) ) {
>       return i;
>     }
>   }
>
>   // if you haven't returned yet it means that tab2 was not found!
>   return -1;
> }
>
> var res = find([ 1, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0], [2, 3, 4, 0]);
> console.log(res);
>
> res = find([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 0], [10, 12, 14, 0]);
> console.log(res);
> ```